# Transform selected excel columns to json string in data factory v2

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

I am having the excel sheet with multiple columns. I need to transform selected column of excel sheet to json string and store in seperate column in excel using Azure Data Factory V2.

In data factory v2 using data flow we can create and update the existing columns using Derived Column Transformation.

I am having below excel file:

[image]

With Azure Data Factory data flow, I need to transform the file to below:

[image]

Please let me know if this is possible to achieve in Derived Columns data flow transformation or I have to use custom activity to achieve the format.

Comment: Hi @user1696555, did my answer meet your request? If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Data Flow could make it as a JSON string. But it's not a real JSON object.

You could try bellow expressions:

```
concat('[{"',Column2,'":',Column3,'}]' )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Leon for the answer!!. File consist more than 300 columns having a specific pattern in column name. Is there a way where I can define the Pattern for column name to concat all columns. Many thanks for the answer

Comment: @user1696555 you're welcome! No, there isn't a good way for convert too many columns.